# ms sql want result from Single table want to generate report

Tags: sql-server

```
Table Schema
(
DeviceLogId int
DeviceId    int
UserId      int
LogDate    datetime
)
```

Table data

```
112 25  66  2015-07-22 11:02:15.000
332 25  66  2015-07-22 17:29:25.000
555 25  88  2015-07-23 19:09:35.000
779 25  67  2015-07-24 16:23:49.000
1003    29  17  2015-07-18 13:03:04.000
```

I want output like

```
Intime                  Outtime                logdate   Incount    OutCount
2015-01-01 10:22:29.000 2015-01-01 19:58:43.000 2015-01-01  7       11
2015-01-02 09:52:26.000 2015-01-02 20:25:25.000 2015-01-02  2       2
```

I have create query  Working for one user id but if I want it for multiple userid

```
select e.Intime,e.Outtime,e.logdate,e.Incount,e.OutCount from
    (
     select a.intime as Intime,b.outtime as Outtime,c.logdate,c.InCount as Incount,d.OutCount as OutCount from    


      ( 
          select min(logdate) intime,cast(LogDate as date) logdate,userid
          from DeviceLogs  where deviceid in (26,31) and  cast(LogDate as date) between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-02' and UserId=7
          group by cast(LogDate as date), UserId
      )a  inner join 
      (
          select max(logdate) outtime,cast(LogDate as date) logdate,userid from DeviceLogs
          where deviceid in (25,30) and   cast(LogDate as date) between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-02' and UserId=7
          group by cast(LogDate as date), UserId
      ) b on a.logdate = b.logdate

      left join 
      (
       select UserId, cast(LogDate as date) logdate ,count(DeviceLogId) as InCount from DeviceLogs 
        where deviceid in (26,31) and  cast(LogDate as date) between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-02' and UserId=7
        Group by UserId, cast(LogDate as date) 
       )c on b.logdate = c.logdate    

       left join
       (
       select UserId, cast(LogDate as date) logdate ,count(DeviceLogId) as OutCount from DeviceLogs 
        where deviceid in (25,30) and  cast(LogDate as date) between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-02' and UserId=7
        Group by UserId, cast(LogDate as date) 
        )d on c.logdate = d.logdate     

    )e
```

So I want to fetch all user data. 
Waiting for reply

I want to retrieve all user data and bind with grid
with better performance

Comment: table data: 2014 (year). Result: 2015. What does your result do?

Comment: I have change the table data as 2015

Answer (score 0):

i don't really understand your reasoning for min() max(). maybe you're trying to show first/last login during the period?

hope it helps:

```
select 
   min(intime)   min_intime, 
   min(outtime)  min_outtime, 
   min(logdate)  min_logdate, 
   max(intime)   max_intime, 
   max(outtime)  max_outtime, 
   max(logdate)  max_logdate,
   count(*)      [tot], 
   userid
from devicelogs
where logdate between '01-01-2000' and '01-01-2001'
group by userid
```

Comment: I want employee office enter time and out time

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help to you.

```
 SELECT inlog.UserId, inlog.date, intime,incount,outtime,ISNULL(outcount,0) 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        ILog.UserId, CAST(ILog.LogDate as date) date , Min(ILog.LogDate) intime, Count(ILog.DeviceLogId) incount
      from 
        DeviceLogs ILog
      where
        ILog.DeviceId in (25) -- in deviceIds
      GROUP BY 
         ILog.UserId, CAST(ILog.LogDate as date)) inlog
LEFT OUTER join 
    (SELECT 
        OLog.UserId, CAST(OLog.LogDate as date) date , Max(OLog.LogDate) outtime, Count(OLog.DeviceLogId) outcount
        from 
        DeviceLogs OLog
        where 
        OLog.DeviceId in (26) -- out deviceIds
        GROUP BY 
        OLog.UserId, CAST(OLog.LogDate as date)) outlog
ON  inlog.UserId =  outlog.UserId
```